# style opinion re. empty If block

Tags: coding-style

I'm trying to curb some of the bad habits of a self-proclaimed "senior programmer."  He insists on writing If blocks like this:

```
if (expression) {}
else {
    statements
}
```

Or as he usually writes it in classic ASP VBScript:

```
If expression Then
Else
    statements
End If
```

The expression could be something as easily negated as:

```
if (x == 0) {}
else {
    statements
}
```

Other than clarity of coding style, what other reasons can I provide for my opinion that the following is preferred?

```
if (x != 0) {
    statements
}
```

Or even the more general case (again in VBScript):

```
If Not expression Then
    statements
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasons that come to my mind for supporting your opinion (which I agree with BTW) are:

1. Easier to read (which implies easier to understand)
2. Easier to maintain (because of point #1)
3. Consistent with 'established' coding styles in most major programming languages

I have NEVER come across the coding-style/form that your co-worker insists on using.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it both ways. McConnell in Code Complete says one should always include both the `then` and the `else` to demonstrate that one has thought about both conditions, even if the operation is nothing (NOP). It looks like your friend is doing this.

I've found this practice to add no value in the field because unit testing handles this or it is unnecessary. YMMV, of course.

If you really want to burn his bacon, calculate how much time he's spending writing the empty statements, multiply by 1.5 (for testing) and then multiply that number by his hourly rate. Send him a bill for the amount.

---

As an aside, I'd move the close curly bracket to the `else` line:

```
if (expression) {
} else {
    statements
}
```

The reason being that it is tempting to (or easy to accidentally) add some statement outside the block.

For this reason, I abhor single-line (bare) statements, of the form

```
if (expression)
  statement
```

Because it can get fugly (and buggy) really fast

```
if (expression)
  statement1
  statement2
```

`statement2` will always run, even though it might look like it should be subject to `expression`. Getting in the habit of always using brackets will kill this stumbling point dead.